# Adwords - KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT Data with test key

Tags: google-ads-api

I have recently got test key for using Adwords API's and i ran through the "GetReportFields" which returned empty data

```
AverageCpc(Money) := []
AverageCpm(Money) := []
AveragePosition(Double) := []
BottomPosition(int) := []
CampaignId(Long) := []
CampaignName(String) := []
```

I do have certain Campaigns in my project and i was hoping to get some meaningful results (atleast with CampaignId and CampaignName) ; is the test account limited to jst showing the fields?

Additionally; i would like to copy these results to my local object; where are entities like "SignificanceData" defined and what type are they?

Thanks,
-Dev

Answer (score 0):

It's called

```
ImpressionSignificance
```

Which is actually the

```
SignificanceData
```